# HTML / CSS Full screen carousel images

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, responsive

For the last couple of days, I have been stuck. I am attempting to create a full screen image slider running in the background of a web page that includes a Navigation bar overlay across the top of the page.

HTML:

```
      <div class="carousel-container">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-left" id="prevButton"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-right" id="nextButton"></i> 

        <div id="nav-bar">      
          <nav>
            <ul>
             <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
             <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
             <li><a href="accomodation.html">Accomodation</a></li>
             <li><a href="rates.html">Rates</a></li>
             <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
             <li><a href="enquire.html">Enquire</a></li>                        
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-slide">
            <img src="./img/paintlive4.jpg" style="width:100%;" id="lastClone" alt="Living room and fireplace4">
            <img src="./img/paintlive1.png" style="width:100%" alt="Living room and fireplace1">
            <img src="./img/living2.JPG" style="width:100%" alt="Living room and fireplace2">
            <img src="./img/living3.JPG" style="width:100%" alt="Living room and fireplace3">
            <img src="./img/paintlive4.jpg" style="width:100%" id="firstClone" alt="Living room and fireplace4">
          </div>     
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-container {

    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;

}

.carousel-slide img{

    height: 700px;
    width: 160%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

 .carousel-slide{

    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 490px;
}
```

as you can see i have given everything I can think of "width:100%" yet the size of the images in my carousel remain only a portion of screen.

I am happy with my nav bar, it will have some opacity to allow the images to be seen through the nav-bar.

I have managed to make the carousel work, (with buttons and JavaScript) however I will need to change it once the image sizes have also changed. Any help in making these images full screen would be very appreciated, Thanks!!

P.S. Sorry if bad formatting, I'm a newbie programmer :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your display is flex witch is making children horizontal

And remove height and width(optional) from carousel-container

I added `flex-direction: column` It's a flex but not horizontal

```css
.carousel-container {


background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-slide img{

height: 700px;
width: 160%;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-slide{

display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
width: 100%;
height: 490px;
}
```

```html
      <div class="carousel-container">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-left" id="prevButton"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-right" id="nextButton"></i> 

        <div id="nav-bar">      
          <nav>
            <ul>
             <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
             <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
             <li><a href="accomodation.html">Accomodation</a></li>
             <li><a href="rates.html">Rates</a></li>
             <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
             <li><a href="enquire.html">Enquire</a></li>                        
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-slide">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" style="width:100%;" id="lastClone" alt="Living room and fireplace4">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" style="width:100%" alt="Living room and fireplace1">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" style="width:100%" alt="Living room and fireplace2">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" style="width:100%" alt="Living room and fireplace3">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" style="width:100%" id="firstClone" alt="Living room and fireplace4">
          </div>     
      </div>
```

Comment: Ah thanks, its been quite difficult writing the CSS as i hardly know the meaning behind each of the different properties, especially flex! :) Thanks

Comment: Flex is a very powerful layout function and my go property for vertical and horizontal alignment, but does take a bit of practice to master it.
I recommend this site for an overview and I still use it as a reference
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to create a carousel and it seems you are getting some techniques mixed up here. For example you have background size and position set in the container, but you are not setting a background image.  Good tip is to avoid inline-styling too if you can, so all your styles are in one place and easy to review and change (remove style="width:100%" from HTML and put it in the CSS file).  Take your nav out of the carousel container too - this shouldnt be part of the carousel.

If you want to go down the flex route, try the following:

```
#carousel-slide {
   width: 100vw;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: flex;
   align-content: stretch;
}

#carousel-slide img{
   width: 100vw;
   height: auto;
   flex-shrink: 0;
   margin: auto 0;
}
```

depending on the size of the images, screen size and look you are going for you can play around with the image width and height. If it's looking good you can use some JS magic to change to next and previous slides. 
Without writing the entire code this is what i was using on a similar task recently..again there are many techniques for this:

```
//next slide event handler
...
const currentScroll = document.getElementById('carousel-slide').scrollLeft();
const newScroll = currentScroll + window.innerWidth;
//do some cool stuff, or nothing when getting to the end of the slider
document.getElementById('carousel-slide').scrollTo({
        left: newScroll,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
...
```

Comment: or make it really easy on yourself and use a library, like bootstrap, to do the work for you: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp

Comment: Hey thank you so much for this, I was very tempted to use the bootstrap carousel library but i wanted to learn the "proper" way. Thanks for getting me there!